# Trying to make sense of convex combinations of more than 2 points

Tags: convex-analysis, simplex

I know that a line segment from point $a$ to point $b$ can be defined by $\{x:x=\alpha a + \beta b\}$ such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$. That is, the convex combination of $\{a, b\}$. We can generalize this to $(n \gt 2)$ dimensions by adding more coefficients. $\{x\in R^n:\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\alpha_i=x\}$ such that $\sum \alpha_i = 1$. When I saw the formula, it didn't look intuitive so I gave a thought and would like someone to correct me.

We'll build these convex combinations recursively starting with a line segment. To build a 2-simplex, we can add a point and take combinations of that point with every other point on the line segment. To build a 3-simplex, take combinations of a new point and all points on the 2-simplex (which we know how to build) and so on.

In symbols ($x_i\in R^n$):

$K_1=\{x_1\alpha+x_2\beta:\alpha+\beta=1\}$

$K_2=\{x_3\alpha+y\beta:y\in K_1 \text{ and } \alpha+\beta=1\}$

$\dots$

$K_n=\{x_{n+1}\alpha+y\beta:y\in K_{n-1} \text{ and } \alpha+\beta=1\}$

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is the way I build combinations correct/equivalent to the other definition?

Comment: You write that you want to generalize from the case of two *points* to more than two *dimensions*. That's a bit weird. The formulas that follow then compute the convex combination of $n$ points in $R^1$ (!), which I'm not certain is what you actually want to do....

Comment: The $K_n$'s are sets of  points in $R^n$

Comment: No, they aren't. If $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in R^n$, then $x_i \in R$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Thus, the expression $x_{i+1}\alpha + y\beta$ doesn't produce a vector, it produces a single real.... I do believe, BTW, that you're basically on the right track with your idea. You just have to make up your mind whether you're generalizing to multiple dimensions or multiple points. Where I'm pretty sure you want the latter, since multiple dimensions are easy - in fact, your formula for two points works for arbitrarily many dimensions...

Comment: Okay, so I have to use dot products right?

Comment: @saadtaame no, you are using scalar products.  $\alpha,\beta$ are scalars that you multiply with the vectors $x_{n+1}$ and $y$.  Just remember that $x_{n+1}$ and $y$ need to have matching dimensions.

Comment: @saadtaame No need for dot products here. Look at your formula for two points, and observe that it works for arbitrarily many dimensions (even infinitely many!), because $x\alpha$ for $x\in R^n$, $\alpha \in R$ is just multiplying a vector with a scalar, which is something that works in *any* vector space. If you want to generalize to multiple points, you need to pick *multiple* points from some $R^n$, not a *single* point from $R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

A correct reformulation of your definition– we have the following recursive definition for the convex hull determined by $n+1$-points in $\mathbb{R}^m$:

- For $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, define $K[\{x_0\}] = \{x_0\}$
- Given $K[S]$ for some set $S\subset \Bbb{R}^m$, define 
  $$K[S\cup \{x_0\}] = \{x_{0}\alpha+y\beta:y\in K[S] \text{ and } \alpha+\beta=1\}$$

That is, for the vectors $x_0,\dots,x_n \in \Bbb{R}^m$ we have
$$
K[\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}] = 
\{x_{n}\alpha+y\beta:y\in K[x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}] \text{ and } \alpha+\beta=1\}
$$
In $\Bbb{R}^m$, the convex hull determined by $m+1$ points is referred to as an $m$-dimensional simplex.

Comment: Yeah, but the same thing works with a notation much closer to the one in the question. In fact, just replacing "a point in $R^n$ is written..." with "$x_i \in R^m$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$" makes the OP's recursive definition work....

Comment: Feel free to improve my answer or post your own. I think the idea I had in mind was to move away from the notion that $K_1,K_2,\dots$ are different functions applied to the same vector.